# add cancel option(x icon) in box of html to disappear it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a `div` with class in HTML and styled it like a box in CSS. I want to add a little cross icon in the top-right of it, and when this is clicked, the `div` should totally disappear, with the space that was containing it.

```css
.cancel {
  width: 93%;
  max-width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4% auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
  background: #111;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cancel">
  <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit this "and it should be totally disappear with its space that was contained" ? perhaps  you mean `absolute` positioning?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I think what they mean is that there should not be an empty white space where the box was, but it should be as if it was never on the page, so for example using `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`

Comment: @ToniMichelCaube I mean when clicked in cross icon it should be disappear with its space taken by it.

Comment: You'll have to use javascript for this, and fire an event when the cross is clicked. This could then add the style `display:none` to the `div`.

Comment: @j08691 oh my god, since 1 week I'm trying this but is not happening.

Comment: @Run_Script exactly, but it is not happening by me. i need your help.

Comment: can i please get the reason of getting downvoted? did i ask any wrong? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've made the javascript. If you want something else to trigger closing the box, just give it the `class="x"` and it will work for that as well.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("x")[0].addEventListener("click", closeBox);

function closeBox(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("cancel")[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.cancel {
  position: relative;
  width: 93%;
  max-width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4% auto;
  padding: 30px 0;
  background: #111;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.x {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cancel">

  <div class="x">❌</div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow @Run_Script that works like a charm, can you also please help me to align cancel to the top-right corner, the unicode of its is "U+274C"

Comment: @Dibas Ok, I've made the edit!